# how to append values to url in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am new to grails.
My need is to append value to url such that...
from a controller, on 
`succes of some action` 
 redirect to new url usingredirect function `redirect(uri: "/login/auth")` .But my actual need is the resulting url should be like this
`/login/auth?successMessage=Created`  ,so that i can take the value of successMessage in the resulting uri. so inorder to do this action what changes must be done in the redirection function of my above controller

Comment: I assume you've tried: `redirect(uri: "/login/auth?successMessage=Created")` ?

Comment: in this case how can i compare value of successMessage in new url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `params` parameter of `redirect` which takes a map of parameters that get appended to the url.

E.g.:

```
redirect controller: 'login', action: 'auth', params: [successMessage: 'Created']
```

/edit:

To answer the question in the comments (in this case how can i compare value of successMessage in new url?):

Within the controller you can then check the value of `successMessage` using `params.successMessage`:

```
def myAction() {
  if (params.successMessage == 'Created') {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly in case of url and also i can take value from the url using `params.successMessage` . but when i am reloading the page it also do the action written in case of `params.successMessage == 'Created'`. Actually i want skip this action while reloading my page

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the code above into an `after-interceptor`